# How to perform search in laravel in relationship using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, laravel

I am using laravel with mongodb.i have to perform search with relationship.this is my code.

```
$user_membership = Membertransaction ::with(array('usermember'=>function($query) use ($value) {
                                   $query->where('members.first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%')
                                   ->orWhere('plan_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$value.'%');
            }))
            ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with following function

```
public function search() {

    $query = DB::table('usermember');

    $query->where('members.first_name', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%")
             ->orWhere('plan_name', 'LIKE', "%{$value}%");



    $results = $query->paginate(10);

}
```